# Cannot get QWindow::fromWinId to work properly

Tags: linux, qt, x11

My Qt 5.9 program (on X11 Linux) launches other applications, using `QProcess`.
I would like to have control over windows these applications spawn, so I obtain their `winId` value and use `QWindow::fromWinId` to get a `QWindow` instance.

The problem is these instances are invalid and do not represent the window they are supposed to.

If I check the `winId` values using `xwininfo`, the correct information is returned, so I know they are good.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: An example won't help much, but here goes:

```
QProcess *process=new QProcess(this);
...
process.open()
... // wait until window appears
WId winId=PidToWid(process->processId()); // this function returns the    Window ID in decimal format. I test this with xwininfo, it's always correct
...
QWindow *appWindow=QWindow::fromWinId(winId);
```

... And that's basically it. appWindow is a valid QWindow instance, but it does not relate to the actual window in any way. For example, if I close() it, it returns true but the window does not close.

Even if I provide a wrong WId on purpose, the end result is the same.

Comment: Cannot tell right away as long as it is maybe X11 specifics but: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#effectiveWinId

Comment: That's not useful, I'm trying to cast the windows of external programs as QWindow instances. This is exactly what QWindow::fromWinId is supposed to do, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: There's not much to show really, but I added the relevant code as an example to my original post.

Comment: You can still create a minimal compilable example, as suggested, although your code is big. Code you showed is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is not proper solution with explanation why it should work, however it may be helpful for somebody...

I had the same issue with my application when I switched from Qt4 QX11EmebeddedContainer to Qt5 implementation using QWindow. What I did to resolve / fix this issue was following:

Client application:

```
widget->show(); //Widget had to be shown
widget->createWinId();
sendWinId(widget->winId()); //Post window handle to master app where is constructed container
```

Master application:

```
QWindow* window = QWindow::fromWinId(clientWinId);
window->show(); //This show/hide toggle did trick in combination with show in client app
window->hide();
QWidget* container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window, parentWindowWidget);
```

After this I was able to control window properly through QWidget container.